# Find missing records in an other table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
tableCars
-------
car       color
---------------
Mercedes  blue
Mercedes  red
Mercedes  white
BMW       blue
BMW       red
BMW       white
AUDI      red
AUDI      white

tableColors
-------
color
-------
blue
red
white
```

I need to find the cars in tableCars that have not all colors in tableColors: AUDI.

It does not look that difficult but I tried left joins and not exists variantions but I can't find the solution.

Comment: What type of technology for SQL?  Oracle, MSSQL, MYSQL, etc?

Comment: Show some of your attempted solution(s) as well.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to count:

```
select ca.car
from Cars ca join
     Colors co
     on ca.color = co.color
group by ca.car
having count(*) <> (select count(*) from Colors);
```

This assumes no duplicates (in either table).  If you have duplicates, then use `count(distinct color)` instead of `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no additional colors besides those in `tablecolor`:

```
select car
from Cars 
group by ca.car
having count(*) <> (select count(*) from Colors);
```

If car/color might have duplicates switch to `count(distinct color)` instead of `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `group by`. Use `having` clause to verify that the car has less than all colors.

```
select car
from cars
group by car
having count(*) < (select count(*) from colors);
```